# How to get a sketch to work within another sketch that is using screens?

Tags: timer, processing, draw, void

I am working a project that involves screens. I want to be able to use the number keys to which screens, which will take the user into an interactive part of the sketch.

I began working on one of the interactive parts of the program in a separate sketch. Here is that sketch:

```java
 float x, y, r, g, b, radius;
int timer;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
      Zon();
  }


void Zon(){
   // use frameCount to move x, use modulo to keep it within bounds
  x = frameCount % width;

  // use millis() and a timer to change the y every 2 seconds
  if (millis() - timer >= 8000) {
    y = random(height);
    timer = millis();
  }

  // use frameCount and noise to change the red color component
  r = noise(frameCount * 0.01) * 255;

  // use frameCount and modulo to change the green color component
  g = frameCount % 1;

  // use frameCount and noise to change the blue color component
  b = 255 - noise(1 + frameCount * 0.025) * 255;

  // use frameCount and noise to change the radius
  radius = noise(frameCount * 0.01) * mouseX;

  color c = color(r, g, b);
  fill(c);
  ellipse(x, y, radius, radius);
}
```

This was the code for the separate sketch. I want to be able to put this sketch into the my actual project, but it is not functioning the way it does in the separate sketch. Can someone explain to me why this is?

I want there to be a white background and for the ellipse to move across the screen, leaving behind a trail. Is it not working because the background is running over and over again, erasing the trail in the process?

When I remove the background(255); it kind of work, except its running on the menu screen, which I don't want.

Here the actual project code:

```java
final int stateMenu = 0;
final int GreenBox = 3;
int state = stateMenu;
float x, y, r, g, b, radius;
int timer; 
PFont font;
PFont Amatic;


void setup()
{
  size(800, 700);
  smooth();
  font = createFont("ARCARTER-78.vlw", 14);
  textFont(font);
  //Amatic = createFont("Amatic-Bold.ttf",60);
  //textFont(Amatic);
  frameRate(15);
} 

void draw()
{
  // the main routine. It handels the states.
  // runs again and again
  switch (state) {
  case stateMenu:
    showMenu();
    break;
    case GreenBox:
    handleGreenBox();
    break;
    default:
    println ("Unknown state (in draw) "
      + state
      + " ++++++++++++++++++++++");
  }
}

  void keyPressed() {
  // keyboard. Also different depending on the state.
  switch (state) {
  case stateMenu:
    keyPressedForStateMenu();
    break;
    case GreenBox:
    keyPressedForGreenBox();
  }
  }

   void keyPressedForStateMenu() {
     switch(key){
       case '3':
       state = GreenBox;
       break;
       default:
    // do nothing
    break;
   }
   }
     void keyPressedForGreenBox(){
      switch(key) {
  default:
    state = stateMenu;
    break;
      }
     }
      void showMenu() {
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  textSize(45);
  //textFont(Amatic);
  text(" Music Box ", 330, 250, 3);
  textSize(14);
  text("Press 3 for Green", 350, 350);

} 

void handleGreenBox() {
      Zon();
} 


void Zon(){
  background(255);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
   // use frameCount to move x, use modulo to keep it within bounds
  x = frameCount % width;

  // use millis() and a timer to change the y every 2 seconds
  if (millis() - timer >= 8000) {
    y = random(height);
    timer = millis();
  }

  // use frameCount and noise to change the red color component
  r = noise(frameCount * 0.01) * 255;

  // use frameCount and modulo to change the green color component
  g = frameCount % 1;

  // use frameCount and noise to change the blue color component
  b = 255 - noise(1 + frameCount * 0.025) * 255;

  // use frameCount and noise to change the radius
  radius = noise(frameCount * 0.01) * mouseX;

  color c = color(r, g, b);
  fill(c);
  ellipse(x, y, radius, radius);
}
```

Can someone help me fix this issue, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code you're not clearing the background, but in the merged code version you are:

```
void Zon(){
  background(255);
 ...
```

and you don't want that as you pointed out.
The only other issue is that you still need to call `background(255)`, but just once, when you switch from the menu state to the GreenBox state:

```
void keyPressedForStateMenu() {
  switch(key) {
  case '3':
    state = greenBox;
    //clear the menu once when moving into greenBox
    background(255);
    break;
  default:
    // do nothing
    break;
  }
}
```

You've done well in identifying the issue and how solve it partially, just needed to clear the background when changing modes.

Your code will look like this:

```
final int stateMenu = 0;
final int greenBox = 3;
int state = stateMenu;

float x, y, r, g, b, radius;
int timer; 
PFont font;
PFont Amatic;


void setup()
{
  size(800, 700);
  smooth();
  //maybe loadFont ?
  font = createFont("ARCARTER-78.vlw", 14);
  textFont(font);
  //Amatic = createFont("Amatic-Bold.ttf",60);
  //textFont(Amatic);
  frameRate(15);
} 

void draw()
{
  // the main routine. It handels the states.
  // runs again and again
  switch (state) {
  case stateMenu:
    showMenu();
    break;
  case greenBox:
    handlegreenBox();
    break;
  default:
    println ("Unknown state (in draw) "
      + state
      + " ++++++++++++++++++++++");
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  // keyboard. Also different depending on the state.
  switch (state) {
    case stateMenu:
      keyPressedForStateMenu();
      break;
    case greenBox:
      keyPressedForgreenBox();
  }
}

void keyPressedForStateMenu() {
  switch(key) {
  case '3':
    state = greenBox;
    //clear the menu once when moving into greenBox
    background(255);
    break;
  default:
    // do nothing
    break;
  }
}
void keyPressedForgreenBox() {
  switch(key) {
  default:
    state = stateMenu;
    break;
  }
}
void showMenu() {
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  textSize(45);
  //textFont(Amatic);
  text(" Music Box ", 330, 250);
  textSize(14);
  text("Press 3 for Green", 350, 350);
} 

void handlegreenBox() {
  Zon();
} 


void Zon() {
  //don't clear the buffer continuously if you want to leave trails
//  background(255);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
  // use frameCount to move x, use modulo to keep it within bounds
  x = frameCount % width;

  // use millis() and a timer to change the y every 2 seconds
  if (millis() - timer >= 8000) {
    y = random(height);
    timer = millis();
  }

  // use frameCount and noise to change the red color component
  r = noise(frameCount * 0.01) * 255;

  // use frameCount and modulo to change the green color component
  g = frameCount % 1;

  // use frameCount and noise to change the blue color component
  b = 255 - noise(1 + frameCount * 0.025) * 255;

  // use frameCount and noise to change the radius
  radius = noise(frameCount * 0.01) * mouseX;

  color c = color(r, g, b);
  fill(c);
  ellipse(x, y, radius, radius);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to draw a background and have a "trail" drawn on top of that background, then you have two options:

**Option 1:** Create a data structure that contains everything you need to draw, and then draw everything in that data structure every frame. This could be as simple as an `ArrayList<PVector>`, or you might be better off creating your own classes that encapsulate everything you need to know in order to draw everything in a frame.

**Option 2:** Create a `PGraphics` that you draw your trail to. Then draw your background to the screen, and then draw that `PGraphics` to the screen. Info on this approach can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html).

Which approach you take really depends on you. I recommend putting together a little example that tests out each to see which one makes more sense to you. Then you can post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of that small example if you get stuck. Good luck.